# Google Drive Integration - "Open with" always prompts "Your domain administrator has approved access to"

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

We have a public Google Apps Market place app with Drive integration enabled. We request all the required privileges at domain wide level at app install time and it seems to be working because non admin users are able to perform seamless SSO.

In drive, when a user selects a file, clicks "Open With", and selects our app to open with, he is prompted with a message as follows:

"Your domain administrator has approved access to "

Sign in As:

This happens each time the user selects a file and not just the first time. How to avoid thus prompt on every "Open With" action.

Comment: In the Drive SDK configuration of the Google Developer Console project, do you have the box checked for "Automatically initiate the OAuth 2.0 flow when users open my application from Drive"?